# Does this creature, generated by ChatGPT, fit within the guidelines for monsters set by WoTC?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, homebrew-review, chatgpt

#### Context

This creature is supposed to be a miniboss in one of my adventures with a dark horror theme. It's intended to be a *hard* encounter for four 3rd level pcs.

##### The questions:

- Is this monster actually a CR 5 monster according to the guidelines for creating monsters as set by WoTC?
- Is the statblock generally consistent?
- Is there information that is missing that needs to be included?
- Are there contradictions that I'm missing?
- Is it overly similar to or a copy of an existing monster?

##### My thoughts so far:

- yes, it is a CR 5 monster. It might have relatively low hit points considering it's AC, (as compared to CR 5 monsters from [this site](https://5thsrd.org/gamemaster_rules/monster_indexes/monsters_by_cr/#5_1), but it makes up for it with high damage output from it's lair action.
- I saw no inconsistencies upon my review of the statblock
- I can see no additional information needed
- I did not notice any contradictions
- I know of no monsters that are overly similar or the same

##### Prompts used:

All of this is done with GPT-4, available to ChatGPT plus users

> how much do you know about dnd 5e monster stablocks? after you answer that, make a plan to create a monster statblock template. consider formatting, including headers, tables, and any other formatting you think is relevant, as well as ALL of the information you need to include. then execute that plan

The AI generates a template after creating a plan. Having the AI create a plan beforehand results in higher quality answers.

> Given this plan and template, create a monster stat block for a single monster encounter that is a hard level encounter for four 3rd level PCs.

The AI generates the stat block given here, provided as markdown file. Some mild formatting changes were made.

### The monster:

> ### Venomous Shadowbeast
>
> *A stealthy and venomous creature that lurks in the darkest corners of the world.*
>
> **Medium Monstrosity, Neutral Evil**
>
> Armor Class **15** Hit Points **68** (8d8+32) Speed **40 ft., climb 30
> ft.**
>
> | STR | DEX | CON | INT | WIS | CHA |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 16 (+3) | 18 (+4) | 18 (+4) | 10 (+0) | 14 (+2) | 8 (-1) |
>
> Saving Throws
>
> - Dex +6
> - Con +6
>
> Skills
>
> - Stealth +8
> - Perception +4
>
> Damage Resistances
>
> - Cold
> - Necrotic
>
> Condition Immunities
>
> - Poisoned
>
> Senses
>
> - Darkvision 60 ft.
> - Passive Perception 14
>
> Languages: **Understands Common, but can't speak**
>
> Challenge: **5** (1,800 XP)
>
> ##### TRAITS
>
> - Shadow Camouflage: The Venomous Shadowbeast has advantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks made to hide in dim light or darkness.
> - Poisonous Blood: When the Venomous Shadowbeast is hit by a melee attack, the attacker must make a DC 14 Constitution saving throw. On a
>   failed save, the attacker takes 7 (2d6) poison damage and is poisoned
>   for 1 minute.
>
> ##### ACTIONS
>
> - Bite: Melee Weapon Attack: +6 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 10 (2d6 + 3) piercing damage plus 7 (2d6) poison damage.
> - Shadow Strike: Ranged Spell Attack: +6 to hit, range 60 ft., one target. Hit: 14 (4d6) necrotic damage.
>
> ##### REACTIONS
>
> - Retaliate: When the Venomous Shadowbeast takes damage from a creature within 5 feet of it, it can make a bite attack against that
>   creature.
>
> ##### LAIR ACTIONS
>
> - Shadowy Grasp: The Venomous Shadowbeast causes tendrils of shadow to reach out from the darkness. Each creature within 10 feet of a point
>   in darkness that the Venomous Shadowbeast can see must make a DC 14
>   Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the creature takes 10 (3d6)
>   necrotic damage and is restrained until the end of its next turn.

Comment: Do you think it is? Have you done an analysis first to see how it works and what may be an issue? What were the prompts that you gave the AI? What new guidelines are you referencing for Monster creation?

Comment: @NautArch Made an edit Addressing your points. Hoping someone with experience than I do can take a look over it.

Comment: Does the AI understand the difference between poison damage and the poisoned condition?  I'm assuming that most monsters immune to the condition would also be immune to damage, or at the very least resistant?

Comment: @Kirt "understand" is a hard concept to define in this case. If I asked the AI directly it absolutely does understand. When doing this I haven't primed it to remember that detail. I certainly think it might be an oversight

Comment: Have you tried to ask ChatGPT those questions? Would be interesting to see how it understands itself.

Comment: Careful on your wording - you misspelled `statblock` in the first question.

Comment: This seems like an extremely deadly encounter for lvl 3's. 4d6 is really high damage output against characters that will only have 3 hit dice worth of HP. If played by the DM as a somewhat intelligent creature, It will oneshot someone from stealth, use its lair action to outright kill or restrain most of the remaining party and easily clean up from there. This becomes a significantly less deadly encounter once the party has a bit more HP to prevent the insta downs due to the creatures low HP.

Comment: @PeterKrebs ChatGPT understand precisely and exactly nothing. Don't confuse its ability to produce plausible looking answers that can be co-incidentally correct with actual understanding.

Comment: @JackAidley I know that - but maybe some day it can be critical of itself. If not useful at least it could be funny, just like ChatGPT always is. Sorry for off-topic.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Technically: CR6 in its lair, CR4 out of its lair, CR2 out of its lair against ranged attackers

The table [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#CreatingQuickMonsterStats) tells us that a CR5 monster should have proficiency +3, AC15, 131-145hp, +6 attack, 33-38dpr, and a DC15 save.

This monster has proficiency +2, AC15, hp68, +6 attack, and the damage is a little bit complicated:

- bite attack 17 damage
- retaliate bite attack 17 damage
- assume 2x poisonous blood per round, 14 damage
- assume 2x shadowy grasp per round, 20 damage

which comes to 64 damage per round as an estimate.

The defensive CR is 1.5 (68hp corresponds to CR 1/2, but plus one for having higher AC).

The offensive CR is 10.

Averaging the two numbers gives CR6.

Outside of its lair, the offensive CR is only seven, and the average CR is four.

Outside of its lair and if nobody is trying to melee-attack the monster, the offensive CR is three and the average CR is two.

### This monster is pretty biased against melee attackers

The *poisonous blood* trait, in particular, is basically telling melee attackers not to bother.  Ten damage *per attack*, and it gives the poisoned condition?  *And* attacking gives the monster a free bite retaliate once per turn? Melee characters will feel tempted to pull out their javelins, or to stand in the monster's face and take the dodge action and hope their allies kill it.

Depending on your group, this could be a fairly easy fight (if they're all ranged attackers, blasting a monster that only has 68hp, and especially if they all have light sources).  Or it could be fairly difficult if they're all melee attackers.

But the most likely way this will go is that your melee characters run into battle unawares, get chewed up by the monster's incredible retaliation traits, and then the ranged attackers try to kill the monster before the melee characters fail their death saves.

### GPT4 shows decent rule comprehension

The derived skills and saves seem consistent assuming a +2 proficiency.  The monster's bite attack seems to assume a +3 proficiency (using its STR mod?), and I'm unsure what stat is generating the +6 spell attack.

If the Poisonous Blood trait and Shadowy Grasp action were written whole-cloth by GPT4 (as they appear to have been) then GPT4 is doing a great job of writing valid 5e rules.

Comment: There are some discrepancies between bonus values and ability modifier/proficiency bonus, but I wouldn’t have expected the machine to grasp that nuance.

Comment: If the lair damage tips the CR to 6, then both you and GPT should note separate CR numbers for encounters outside and within the lair, as is done, for example, with a demilich.

Comment: Okay, seems fair.

Comment: @Kirt and DanB: upon submitting this prompt to gpt-4 "Do an analysis of this monster and determine if it is biased against ranged or melee attacks, if it's CR is correct, including factors like whether it is in it's lair, and check for contradictions or inconsistencies. Then Self reflect on whether there are other improvements you can make. Once you've done this, please create a plan to fix any errors you find, then execute that plan", It correctly identifies this as a CR-6 creature in it's lair with bias towards melee combat, but does NOT identify two separate CR values.

Comment: CR5 monster should have +3 Prof bonus, not +2. If you stat monster-not-inlair as CR4, then +2 is correct for both variations.

Comment: One highly unusual thing about this monster is that it has a Lair action with only CR5. The only other monster I am aware about that has one is the Unicorn at CR5, (and the Merrenoloth at CR3). Normally Lair actions only become common around CR9.

Comment: I don't know. It wrote up a very generic-sounding, horribly unbalanced monster that averages out at CR 6, not CR 5 and which probably only seems to (almost) mathematically be consistent because there are some published monsters with similar stats.

Comment: @DanB My comment is more on the line of "are you sure it works that way? It looks weird." And less "I want to know exactly how it works".

Comment: Okay!  In that case: yes, I'm sure it works that way.